# OD Cost Matrix does not work from every origin to every destination?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm trying to run OD Cost Matrix function for my term project and i run into a problem. I have 2566 origins and 3 destinations and I am trying to calculate distance base origin cost matrix from every origin point to every destination point but as you can see in figure, only 43 lines appeared. The problem is not about my network. I used the default settings for building the network. The error message is : Warning: No "Destinations" found for "Location 1" in "Origins" for every origin. I could not figure what the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your input parameters into the OD matrix tool?

Comment: Do you have a cutoff value set in your origin properties or analysis settings?

Comment: i just want to calculate the length between every origin and every destination. I have 3km cutoff value for pedestrians. I want to know the distances and choose the best by looking its destination rank. I just have the network data and points data.

Comment: Make sure the origins can be located onto the network by using a high tolerance. I don't know your scale, but maybe try increasing the 3km cutoff value. Also double check that your network is properly connected and no roads are isolated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a network problem.

When that happens to me it's usually due to the restrictions settings not allowing a path from an origin to any destination. As a diagnostic tool, try running 1 origin to 1 destination that you know failed (as in "No Destinations Found") as a **Closest Facility** model in Network Analyst instead of OD Cost Matrix. That way, if it's failing in OD Cost Matrix, you can see the actual path it's supposed to take in Closest Facility, which should point you to where in the process it is failing. If Closest Facility cannot draw a polyline from your origin to your destination, it's a network dataset settings issue. If you do get a path drawn, it's your OD Cost Matrix analysis settings. You may also want to revisit the settings you chose when loading locations--that could be affecting how your origins and destinations snapped to the network to begin with.